# ForeignKey Goes NULL After a second UpdateWithChildren()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am using **SQLiteNetExtension** for **XAMARIN Forms project (PCL)**. the problem which I am facing is the the ForeignKey for a many-to-one relationship which is defined in the many end of the relationship is Overrided with Null after a second **_connectionToDB.UpdateWithChildren()**:

- First Insertion Correct
- Second Insertion (same values) : Insertion Success but ForeignKey Goes NULL
- Third Data handling : database holds 4 rows with 2 foreign keys NULL and 2 others correct
- Fourth Data handling : the 4 rows in the database have a NULL FK

*(By data handling I mean executing the same code per each button click ..Example )*

let's get to the code :

```cs
public class Bus
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull, Unique] //it's not AutoIncrement because it's unique 
    public String Id { get; set; }

    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<Person> Passengers { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull, Unique]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Bus))]
    public String BusId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public Bus Bus { get; set; }
}
```

now DB and data handling

```cs
var Persons = new List<Person>();
Bus B10 = new Bus {Id = "15458 ghf 14" ; PlateNumber = "122541 tn 154";}
_connectionToDB.InsertOrReplace(B10);

Person P1 = new Person{Id=15547; Name= Robert };
_connectionToDB.InsertOrReplace(P1);
Persons.Add(P1);

Person P2 = new Order {Id=25547;Name= Katherina};
_connectionToDB.InsertOrReplace(P2);
Persons.Add(P2);

B10.Passengers = Persons ;
_connectionToDB.UpdateWithChildren(B10);
```